# Show Div and Hide All Others When Selected

Tags: jquery

This seems like it should be easy, but I haven't gotten it working yet. I have an html select element with 10 or so options. When the user selects one of the options, a Div is displayed by removing the .hidden class, which is just a class with display:none in the CSS. This all works fine, but when I select the next option, the previous div stays visible. I tried using .toggleClass, but that didn't work.

```
$(function () {
  $("#calc-select").change(function () {
    $('#' + $("#calc-select").val()).removeClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

Comment: are you adding the hidden class back in?

Comment: I tried .toggleClass instead of removeClass, but it had the same effect. Ultimately what I want is to add it back to all of the other Divs. Maybe some sort of .each to iterate through the options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is save the previously selected option in a variable like so

```js
$(function () {
  var prevSelected = $("#Test1");

  $("#calc-select").change(function () {
      $('#' + $("#calc-select").val()).removeClass('hidden');
      prevSelected.addClass('hidden');
      prevSelected = $('#' + $("#calc-select").val());
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="calc-select">
  <option>Test1</option>
  <option>Test2</option>
  <option>Test3</option>
  <option>Test4</option>
  <option>Test5</option>
</select>

<div id="Test1">
Content 1
</div>
<div id="Test2" class="hidden">
Content 2
</div>
<div id="Test3" class="hidden">
Content 3
</div>
<div id="Test4" class="hidden">
Content 4
</div>
<div id="Test5" class="hidden">
Content 5
</div>
```

Now what this jQuery code does is set the first selected value to the first option. Next what it does is remove hidden class, then adds the class back to the previous selected. Finally, it reassigns previously selected element to currently selected element. This way, the previously selected is constantly updated, and the `div`s are shown and hidden accordingly.

Comment: That worked. Thanks! And thanks for the thorough explanation.

Comment: Happy to help, if you've got any other questions, let me know @TonyTambe :)